# Does reserved word 'then' can always be replaced with semicolon or linebreak?

Tags: ruby, reserved-words

Does using `then` instead of semicolon or linebreak have only decorative purpose (to make code more *readable*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `then` can appear in two places in ruby: `if` statements and `case` statements. In both cases it can be replaced with a linebreak or a semicolon.

So yes, it's merely decorative.

Answer (score 0):

In `if` expressions and `case` expressions, the condition is terminated either with the `then` keyword or an expression separator (i.e. semicolon or newline).

So, yes it can always be replaced with semicolon or linebreak.

And no, it does not have only decorative purpose, it separates the consequence from the condition in an `if` or `case` expression.

Comment: 'Decorative purpose' was asked about *using it instead of ...* Excuse me please, I'll correct question.